# Compare Dates as number in typescript

Tags: typescript

A long time, I have 4 String , 2 for Client and 2 for Server(mock), this Strings was as Dates "03/06/2016" in client and "2018-11-23T00:00:00+01:00" in server.

I translate the Strings to Dates and again to String for same format String "dd/mm/aaaa" then I place the String with Split and finally I parseInt.

When I got 2 numbers I can compare and filter in angular, well, It runs but now I dont have my server(mock) and now I don't know why It doesnt run...

```
 transformDate(filterDate: string) {

    let date: any;

    if (filterDate !== undefined && filterDate !== '') {
      let day, month;

      date = filterDate.split('/');

      day = date[0];
      month = date[1];

      if (day.lenght < 2) {
        day = '0' + day;
      }

      if (month.length < 2) {
        month = '0' + month;
      }

      date = parseInt(date[2] + month + day, 10);

    } else {
      date = false;
    }

    return date;
  }

 public filterResult(url: string, id: number, filterDateStart: string, filterDateEnd: string): Observable<any> {

return this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(map(param => {

  let filter, dateStart, dateEnd;

  dateStart = this.transformDate(filterDateStart);
  dateEnd = this.transformDate(filterDateEnd);

  if (!isNaN(id)) {
    filter = param.filter(
      dato => dato.id === id);
  } else {
    if (!dateStart && !dateEnd) {
      filter = param;
    } else {
      if (dateStart && dateEnd) {
        filter = param.filter(dato => {

        if (
            this.transformDate(new Date(dato.startdatevalidity).toLocaleDateString()) >= dateStart
            && this.transformDate(new Date(dato.enddatevalidity).toLocaleDateString()) <= dateEnd
        ) {
          return filter = dato;
        } else {
          console.log( 'no entro');
          console.log( 'en cliente inicio' , dateStart);
          console.log( 'en cliente fin' , dateEnd);

          console.log( 'servidor inicio', this.transformDate(new Date(dato.startdatevalidity).toLocaleDateString()));
          console.log( 'servidor fin', this.transformDate(new Date(dato.enddatevalidity).toLocaleDateString()));

          console.log('type' , typeof(this.transformDate(new Date(dato.startdatevalidity).toLocaleDateString())) );
          console.log('type' , typeof(dateStart) );

        }});
      } else {

        if (dateStart && !dateEnd) {
          filter = param.filter(dato => {
            if (this.transformDate(new Date(dato.startdatevalidity).toLocaleDateString()) >= dateStart) {
              return filter = dato;
            }});
        } else {
          filter = param.filter(dato => {
            if (this.transformDate(new Date(dato.enddatevalidity).toLocaleDateString()) <= dateEnd) {
              return filter = dato;
            }});
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return filter;
}));
```

[image]

In this example I tried with DateStart and DateFinish, as range of Dates

Comment: Hello. Why don't you use libs like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) ? It would be easier.

Comment: sorry, I don't know that...

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use libs like **[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)**.

From documentation [Moment.js for Typescript](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/) :

> As of version 2.13.0, Moment includes a typescript definition file.
>
> **Install via NPM**
>
> ```
> npm install moment
> ```
>
> **Import and use in your Typescript file**
>
> ```
> import * as moment from 'moment';
> ```

Then, this is one example of how you can compare dates with `Moment.js` :

> **Is Before 2.0.0+**
>
> ```
> moment().isBefore(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array);
> moment().isBefore(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array, String);
> ```
>
> Check if a moment is before another moment. The first argument will be
>   parsed as a moment, if not already so.
>
> ```
> moment('2010-10-20').isBefore('2010-10-21'); // true
> ```

You can find the complete documentation about date comparison [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/).

I hope this will help you.